# USB camera cause crashes when turn off

Tags: windows-10, usb, camera

I have an USB 3.0 Camera that works properly till I turn it off (by closing the Camera application or unplugging the USB cable). After it is turned off, the whole PC crashes and I have to restart it. I tried it on several PCs and got the same behavior.

My question: Where can I start debugging the problem? Any clue is much appreciated!

P.S. The camera does not have a special driver that I have installed manually. I just plugged it and it started working.

OS: Windows 10 (Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134)

Comment: If it's the same result on different PC's, it's pretty clear that the problem lies with the camera itself.

Comment: @NiallJones Yes I totally agree. However, I have no support or a replacement for the camera right now and I need it urgently. So I was wondering if there is any hack to make it work.

Comment: If it's drivers are up to date, i'd suggest to just not unplug it..